# I can not add a style using the selector

Tags: android

I have styles

```
<resources xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<style name="TextStyle" > 
        <item name="android:textSize">8sp</item> 
        <item name="android:textColor">#0A0A0A</item> 
        <item name="android:typeface">serif</item> 

</style>

 <style name="TextStylePressed" > 
        <item name="android:textSize">18sp</item> 
        <item name="android:textColor">#0A0A0A</item> 
        <item name="android:typeface">serif</item> 
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item> 
        <item name="android:background">#C2C2C2</item>   
</style>

</resources>
```

and I use selector arrow.xml

```
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item android:drawable="@style/TextStylePressed" android:state_selected="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@style/TextStylePressed" android:state_pressed="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@style/TextStylePressed" android:state_focused="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@style/TextStyle" />

</selector>
```

**The problem is that I can not understand - if it works?**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    style="@drawable/arrow"               //  <---- Framed here
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/arrow" //  <---- then here
    android:orientation="vertical" > 

</LinearLayout>
```

**Consequently, after all attempts nothing happens**

Comment: Does you file is really named as `Arrow.xml` (first letter upper) ?

Comment: sorry I made a mistake arrow.xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK selectors can only be defined to select a `drawable` and not any other `attribute`. If you check the [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#StateList) , it compiles to StatelistDrawable, So i believe it can only be used for drawables

Comment: difficult to understand what I did wrong   <item android:drawable="@style/TextStylePressed" android:state_selected="true"/> you mean to say there should be "@drawable/TextStylePressed"  ?

Comment: yes, only drawables work for selector. so you cannot set android:textColor or any other attribute through selector

Comment: tell me please I created a LinearLayout android: background = "@ drawable / arrow" it works but <item android:state_pressed="true"> does not work why?

Comment: Maybe state selected is also true when you do state pressed, since state selected is at top, it takes precedence

Comment: Add a new topic because it is difficult explained to